# Django ORM: can I have a BooleanField associated to a char column in the database?

Tags: python, django, orm

I "inherited" a database from an old system we have, in which (among other ugly things) there's a column in a certain table that should be boolean, instead it is a varchar(1) with 'N' or '0' to represent false, and 'Y' or '1' to represent true (different parts of the code using one or the other convention when writing, but apparently all of them are able to recognize both when reading).

I'm porting/rewriting the system, originally written in Java, to Python+Django, and I'll be able to shut down the old one and "clean" the database mess only when the port is complete.

I'd like to make the field in the model class to appear externally as a boolean, so when the database is finally corrected, the only thing I'll have to do in the code is to change the field to a plain BooleanField. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: There's a related important tip at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988171/custom-fields-to-python-not-working-django

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own field class that act like you want by subclassing [django.db.models.Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#writing-a-field-subclass) and by implementing the [to_python](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.to_python) method e.g.

```
from django.db import models

class MyField(models.CharField):

     def to_python(self, value):
         if value in ('Y', '1'):
             return True
         if value in ('N', '0'):
             return False
         raise ValueError
```

Hope this will give you some insight :)

Comment: shouldn't you also implement get_prep_value() to convert the boolean value back to a char for storing in the database?

Comment: @Ron: Yes, i forgot about writing in the DB, +1 for you :)

Answer (score 3):

My situation is similar but the legacy data consistently uses Y and N to represent True and False but, I have the addition problem of some of the fields allowing Null. So here are my custom field types. I think they are a little more complete examples of what you can do in this situation and I also inherited from the BooleanField types which I think works better for displaying/editing these fields in forms.

```
from django.db import models

class YNBooleanField(models.BooleanField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 1
        super(YNBooleanField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value in ('Y', 'y'):
            return True
        elif value in ('N', 'n'):
            return False
        else:
            raise ValueError

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value:
            return 'Y'
        else:
            return 'N'

class NullYNBooleanField(models.NullBooleanField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 1
        super(NullYNBooleanField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        elif value in ('Y', 'y'):
            return True
        elif value in ('N', 'n'):
            return False
        else:
            raise ValueError

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        elif value:
            return 'Y'
        else:
            return 'N'
```